# How to view issues after 100 for Major(100 of 973) in Sonar Qube Integrated with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

Upon Integration of sonar qube in eclipse, Under Sonar Qube issues in eclipse, it shows like Major(100 of 973). My Question is how to view Major issues after 100 ?. feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "SonarQube Issues" view, go to "Configure Contents...". Then, set the "Number of items visible per group" to the desired value.

Comment: Thanks David, I was searching for the same menu option under view section but failed. Thanks